# Unable to update the contents of a Generic List

Tags: c#, generics

I have a simple class which has boolean field:

```
public struct Foo { bool isAvailable; }
```

Now I have a List of foos:

```
List < Foo >  list = new List< Foo >();
```

Later on I enumerate each foo in the list and try to update its  isAvailable field:

```
foreach(Foo foo in list) {
    foo.isAvailable = true; 
}
```

But the above code never updates the list. What am I doing wrong here and what's its remedy.

Comment: You have "forgotten" to post the relevant pieces of the code (the ones probably containing the bug). Show us how you fill the list with instances of "Foo" and how you check that the list was not updated.

Comment: Is your `Foo` maybe declared as struct instead of class?

Comment: It seems that your field is private.

Comment: Thanks Jon et all..u make life so easy..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because `Foo` is a mutable struct.

When you fetch the value from the list, it's making a copy - because that's how value types behave. You're changing the copy, leaving the original value unchanged.

Suggestions:

- You probably should be using a class
- **Don't create mutable structs.** They behave in ways which can be hard to predict, or at least not the way you might expect when you're not explicitly thinking about it.

While you *could* change your code to iterate over the list in a different way and replace the value each time, it's generally a bad idea to do so. Just use a class... or project your list to a *new* list with the appropriate values.

---

**Original answer, when Foo was a class**

It should work fine. For example, here's a short but complete program which *does* work:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Foo
{
    public bool IsAvailable { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name + ": " + IsAvailable;
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<Foo> list = new List<Foo>()
        {
            new Foo { Name = "First", IsAvailable = true },
            new Foo { Name = "Second", IsAvailable = false },
            new Foo { Name = "Third", IsAvailable = false },
        };

        Console.WriteLine("Before:");
        list.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
        Console.WriteLine();

        foreach (Foo foo in list)
        {
            foo.IsAvailable = true;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("After:");
        list.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
    }
}
```

Try to adapt your current code to a similar short but complete program which *doesn't* work, post that, and we can work out what's going on.

Comment: hey Jon I am using IsAvailable as a field, does that make any difference? And Foo is a struct rather than a class

Comment: @munna: Ah, it's the fact that it's a struct which is important. Will edit.

Answer (score 2):

You're using a struct as `Foo`, not a class. Structs are copied, not referenced, and therefore you only modify the copy and not the object stored in the list.

So you basically have two options:

- Make it a class
- Re-assign the result to the list. To do so, I'd iterate using an index instead of using `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

When you fill list, you need to create new istance for each Foo Class.

List list = new List();
   Foo foo = new Foo();

foo.isAvailable = false;
   list.Add(foo);

foo = new Foo();
   list.Add(foo);

foo = new Foo();
   list.Add(foo);

if you fill on this way:

List list = new List();
   Foo foo = new Foo();
   list.Add(foo);
   list.Add(foo);
   list.Add(foo);

you are reference on same memory location on stack for each object.